# How to pass domain name to Nginx conf through chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, chef-infra

I have installed Nginx through chef, but i have to pass "AWS instance Public IP to Chef Recipe"

I am creating AWS instance, and installed my application on that Instance through Chef.

I have to run nginx with my default installation method and my Nginx.conf configuration file

So how we can I take the newly created instance Public IP or EC-2 URL in my Nginx configuration i.e. in place of server_name so that I can browse the URL? OR How can I pass the domain name to Nginx.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EC2 meta-data:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

To get the list of all available keys, try this:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
product-codes
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
```

Nevertheless **server_name** can be empty, see [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> If no server_name is defined in a server block then nginx uses the
>   empty name as the server name. Nginx versions up to 0.8.48 used the machine’s hostname as the server
>   name in this case. If a server name is defined as “$hostname” (0.9.4),
>   the machine’s hostname is used.

Comment: Thanks Anatoly.... But i am using Chef tool, So in chef tool .

How can I pass the Instance IP or EC2 URL  in Aws console to Nginx.conf  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of ohai plugin ec2 wich gives correct attributes, mainly `node['ec2']['public_ipv4']` for this case.

the drawback is taht ohai can't guess itself you're on an AWS instance and does not run the plugin, for this you have to create a hint file, hoepfully there's a [cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ohai) for this.

There's example to create the hints within a chef run too, but they're quite complex IMO, here's what I would do (untested, comment if it break):

```
# Resource to reload the ec2 plugin if the hint is created
ohai 'ec2' do
  plugin 'ec2' 
  action :nothing
end

ohai_hint 'ec2' do
  notifies :reload, 'ohai[ec2]', :immediately # to force ohai to run the ec2 plugin now
end
```

You nedd this recipe early in your run list, and this ercipe's cookbook must have a `depends 'ohai'` in it's `metadata.rb` for the ohai cookbook to be loaded.